# Qual é a melhor forma de concatenar strings em Python?

Tags: python, string, concatenação-de-string

Sei que consigo concatenar strings com `+=`, `+`, `join()` e `append()`. Todas elas me dão o mesmo resultado quando concateno duas strings.

Qual é a melhor forma de concatenar strings em Python? Qual é a diferença entre as citadas? Quando usar cada uma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em Python as strings são imutáveis e por essa razão, quando concatenamos duas delas usando o operador “+” um novo objeto do tipo string é criado e os objetos originais perdem as suas referências.

Uma maneira eficiente de fazer essa concatenação é através da utilização de listas (list()) que são estruturas mutáveis e, posteriormente, transformar essa lista de strings em uma única string, concatenando-as com o método join() do objeto str():

## jeito ineficiente

```
a = ""
for i in range(1000):
   a += "X"
print a
```

Desta maneira vc cria vários objetos em memória, diminuindo assim o poder de processamento apenas para concatenar os dois objetos

## jeito eficiente

```
a = []
for i in range(1000):
   a.append('X')
a = ''.join(a)
```

desta maneira vc reaproveita o objeto ja criado na memoria, otimizando seu poder de processamento.

Tem um link interessante falando sobre operações com strings em python [neste link](https://gabrielacavalcante.gitbooks.io/python/content/operacoes_com_strings.html)

Comment: Tem um trabalho interessante aqui, com estatísticas de desempenho: https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/