# Criar dicionários em python usando listas

Tags: python, dicionário

Estou tentando criar um tradutor que traduz palavras em português para código binário. Já consegui fazer isso para digitar apenas uma palavra, porém quando tento usar 2 palavras, no caso "ab", nada acontece. Gostaria de saber o que falta colocar para que o programa também funcione com palavras.

```
dicionario = {'a': '01100001', 'b' : '01100010'}
palavra = str(input('Digite a palavra que deseja traduzir para código binário:'))
if palavra[:] in dicionario:
        print(dicionario[palavra[:]])
```

Comment: Essa representação é seguindo a tabela ASCII, certo? Então não existe a possibilidade de entrar com caracteres acentuados? Ou deve ser levado em conta a codificação dos mesmos?

Comment: Eu acredito que você precisa concatenar os caracteres digitados, tem uma pergunta que ensina isso aqui no SO([Nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187589/qual-%C3%A9-a-melhor-forma-de-concatenar-strings-em-python)). Ou isso ou juntar o que for digitado numa lista, e a partir dessa lista você devolve para o dicionario e "traduz" para binário.

Answer (score 2):

O `if` que está a utilizar:

```
if palavra[:] in dicionario:
```

Testa se a `palavra` escrita existe no `dicionario` como um todo, que não é o que pretende. A solução passa por analisar letra a letra da palavra e ir buscar o binário correspondente ao `dicionario`.

Assumindo que tem a codificação para todas as letras pode fazer assim:

```
traduzido = ''.join(dicionario[letra] for letra in palavra)
```

Para cada `letra` em `palavra` obtêm a codificação com `dicionario[letra]` e vai juntando à `string` através de `join`.

**Criando os binários**

No entanto com apenas dois carateres codificados o código anterior não iria funcionar para um texto real. Uma solução passa por gerar a codificação para os vários carateres que existem na tabela ASCII:

```
for x in range(255):
  dicionario[chr(x)] = "{:08b}".format(x)
```

O `chr(x)` obtem o caratere correspondente ao número em que o `for` vai, ao passo que o `"{:08b}".format(x)` cria a representação binária desse numero com 8 dígitos colocando zeros como preenchimento.

Juntando tudo:

```
dicionario = {} #agora vazio pois são gerados
palavra = str(input('Digite a palavra que deseja traduzir para código binário:'))

#este for gera os carateres de 0 a 255 que correspondem a tabela ASCII
for x in range(255):
  dicionario[chr(x)] = "{:08b}".format(x)

traduzido = ''.join(dicionario[letra] for letra in palavra)
print("Tradução em binário: ", traduzido)
```

[Exemplo online no Ideone](https://ideone.com/mdPT6e)