# Como coloco o valor de uma variavel em uma declaração de outra variavel?

Tags: python, string, variáveis, declaração-de-variável

```
NomeDoProduto1 = str(input("Qual o seu primeiro produto? "))
NomeDoProduto2 = str(input("Qual o seu segundo produto? "))
NomeDoProduto3 = str(input("Qual o seu terceiro produto? "))
PrecoProduto1 = float(input("Digite o preço do")) print(NomeDoProduto1)
```

No código acima quero que na linha 4 que no print apareça a mensagem digite o preço do:(e aqui apareça o nome do primeiro produto). Tipo se na linha 1 eu disse que o nome do meu produto é açúcar então quero q na linha 4 apareça (digite o preço do açúcar).

desconsidere a linha 2 e 3 que e do meu código. estava tentando fazer assim porem da erro de sintaxe. sei que é um erro básico tbm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de múltiplas formas.

**1) Concatenando as strings**

Como você percebeu pode apenas concatenar as strings:

```
PrecoProduto1 = float(input("Digite o preço do:" + NomeDoProduto1))
```

**2) Múltiplas chamadas de `print` sem quebra de linha**

Você pode fazer chamadas diferentes à função `print`, mas definir que você não deseja adicionar a quebra de linha no final, que é adicionado por padrão no Python.

```
print('Digite o preço do: ', end='')
print(NomeDoProduto1, end='')
PrecoProduto1 = float(input())
```

Não recomendo... prefira a opção 3 sempre.

**3) Interpolação de valores**

A partir da versão 3.6 do Python existem as *f-strings* que permitem você fazer a interpolação de strings:

```
PrecoProduto1 = float(input(f"Digite o preço do {NomeDoProduto1}: "))
```

Perceba o prefixo `f` na *string* (por isso o nome *f-string*).

Mais informações:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264722/5878
- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como concatenar multiplas Strings em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82733/5878)
- [Qual é a melhor forma de concatenar strings em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187589/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se devo responder minhas perguntas, porem pesquisando aqui vi que é só colocar um "+" depois de fechar aspas e o nome da variável. tipo:

```
PrecoProduto1 = float(input("Digite o preço do:" + NomeDoProduto1))
```